# How to connect localhost to Swift API?

Tags: swift, api, localhost

I am working on an app that uses an API. I am trying to connect using localhost:8000 but it will not connect. It will get feedback when I use APIs not using localhost and it connects just fine when I use an address bar on chrome. But unfortunately, it will not work where I need it. Also, it will work sometimes and will quit working randomly. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "localhost" is whatever device your app is running on. You do not want "localhost" unless the server is your local app.

Comment: You should provide some additional information. What kind of server you have? Where it runs? Does it the same computer you develop on?

What kind of Swift application you write? Does it macOS application? It runs on the same computer?

Also good idea to add some Swift code with which you try to connect to the API.